# how can i speed up GRASS i.segment?

Tags: grass-gis, performance

I'm trying to find a way for speeding up the segmetation process, it's using little resources (7% memory), and I think I can give it a little more core or memory to speed it up, I already set the memory parameter to 8000 but it makes no difference at all,

My command:
`i.segment group=e15a51f_g seeds=e15a51f_seg output=e15a51f_seg_3min200 threshold=0.3 min=200 memory=8000`

even with a lower threshold (0.01) and smaller size (50), it takes more than 150 mins for a 35 M cell raster (orthophoto); in the shell (top function) it says it uses 99% CPU (it must be a core) and 5.5% memory.

I'm running GRASS 7.2.1 on linux mint sonya and also on windows 10, on a AMD A10 with 12 GB RAM

Comment: Could you please post your full `i.segment` command including all the parameters?

Comment: It would be best to add this information as an edit to your question.

Comment: Please also add the GRASS GIS version and operating system to the question

Answer (score 1):

I gave memory=10000 and now it's using over 1,600 MB, it is way faster

Comment: And is using more resources?

Comment: It's using more resources, but i noticed (after you commented) that it adds up as the process progresses, starts around 900 and tops at 1600 MB, I'm not sure if having reinstalled and upgraded to 7.2.2 did the trick